# How to get this bash script to work if the variable "fileName" contains space?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

```
#!/bin/bash -x

echo "Enter file name: "
read fileName
fileName=`pwd`"/$fileName"
if [ -f $fileName ]; then
    echo "file is present"
fi
```

Even if I change the value of fileName by adding quotes at starting and end.. The script still doesnt work.

Comment: Use: `fileName=$(pwd)/"$fileName"` or even `fileName="$PWD/$fileName"`; then you just need to worry about the user typing /dev/null rather than a name relative to the current directory (also, perhaps, the user typing ../../../../../../etc/passwd).  Final point: middleCapitals look really weird in a shell script.

Comment: ya.. its better to use environment variable. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrapping it in double-quotes works for me:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

echo "Enter file name: "
read fileName
fileName=`pwd`"/$fileName"
if [ -f "$fileName" ]; then
        echo "file is present"
fi
```

I believe this will take care of most special characters, including quotes themselves.

Answer (score 5):

You must use the quotes in the `if` as well:

```
if [ -f "$fileName" ]; then
```

Answer (score 3):

Change `if [ -f $fileName ]; then` to `if -f "$fileName" ];`. Otherwise when the file contains a space the -f operation will be passed more than one argument. If you passed in a file named "this file", the shell will expand it to:

```
if [ -f this file ]; then
```

causing the error.

Answer (score 2):

You can quote the filename when you do the -f test. Try this instead

```
#!/bin/bash -x
echo "Enter file name: "
read fileName
fileName=`pwd`/$fileName
if [ -f "$fileName" ]; then
    echo "file is present"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

You're prepending the pwd even if the user entered an absolute path. Try this:

```
case "$fileName" in
    /*) ;; # okay
    *)  fileName=`pwd`/"$fileName"
esac
```

This will only prepend the pwd if fileName doesn't start with a /.

Also, your `if` test will only succeed if fileName is a regular file. If you want it to succeed for directories and the like, test with `-e` instead of `-f`.

Answer (score 1):

Surround filename with quotes:

```
if [ -f "$fileName" ]; then
```